Does efflorescence indicate a faulty French drain setup?
We bought a house that needed new French drain and had no foundation waterproofing. We invested $50k to dig out the entire house down to the footer. There a foundation company repaired our block foundation, installed blueskin, then R-10 rated styrofoam boards and installed Delta dimple membrane on top. They installed a perforated corrugated pipe at the footer level with lots of gravel, so that the rain water would slide down the dimple board into the pipes.
It was done in November. Now we started having issues with the basement slab. We are getting efflorescence, which suggests that there is some ground water reaching the slab. That shouldn't be the case because the drain pipes are installed below the slab and all ground water should be collecting there.
I called the foundation company, they came to check it out, called it weird but didn't propose any solutions. They explained to me, however, that the the drain around the house is completely level but it connects to another pipe that is supposed to move the water away into the ditch and that pipe is installed sloping away from the house with about 2% slope.
The problem is that since the installation this ditch pipe has been completely dry and never had any water coming out. I asked the company about that and they told me that this pipe is supposed to be dry unless there is like abundance of water that fills the drainage pipes around the house, and then because the ditch pipe is actually lower than the pipes around the house, only then the water will come out in the ditch. Otherwise, the drain pipes around the house will let the water pass further into the ground.
It made wonder if the drain was installed correctly, because if it was, then why am I getting efflorescence at the slab?
I have attached a drawing of how the drain was installed.


I think your primary assumption--that a drainage loop will prevent all water intrusion--is faulty. Water can come up from underneath as readily as it can come in laterally. Maybe more easily. Your house isn't a boat. Do you see actual moisture?

If you have groundwater, it's everywhere, not just outside the perimeter of your home.  If the water table is higher than your footings, the french drain will collect water from immediately outside the "tub" but water can still come up directly below your slab.

Not sure a full answer but I went through similar situation and learned lots about this. Same thing came to mind as isherwood & Heusmann's comments. Water can accumulate from below the slab, below and around the footer, and against the sides of basement walls. In my situation and I imagine most, the problem was mainly from water pressure against the walls, resulting in efflorescence on walls and (when soil over-saturated) bulk water seeping in where walls meet slab. I also had an area where a slab drain was overflowing with groundwater. All these were addressed with an interior french drain.
The interior french drain seems to have an important design difference. Some images below highlight what I'm thinking. Again, I'm no pro, just a fellow homeowner who had a similar project done last year.

With the drain you described, it doesn't look like there is a way to release groundwater building up beneath the slab. Some or most of the time, it could be true that under the slab stays pretty dry because it has a roof on top of it, and water draining in from around it will be handled and moved away via your exterior french drain. Depending on your soils and groundwater conditions though, it is likely that at the wettest times, basically the entire soil profile has moisture in it. In that case, even if your exterior french drain works to dry out soil around walls, water could find its way up (because there will be open pores and lower pressure areas under the slab, compared with saturated higher-pressure pores in deeper soils below the slab). I imagine you wouldn't notice this much, given the gravel gap that can hold and drain whatever water comes up, and it seems like it would take a lot of groundwater pushing up to wick into the slab and leave efflorescence. But conditions vary and I am no expert on concrete wicking moisture.
For comparison, this interior french drain would be draining water that's up against the blocks (entering drainage system via weep holes in blocks, or through waffle board catching condensation). It also catches water coming up against the slab.

Keep in mind, the 'water table' and 'aquifer' are just soil with all pores full of water. Groundwater does not follow the same topography as surface soils, instead groundwater follows pressure gradients (and to map groundwater flows, wells need to be dug and pressure tested at each, to make a topography-like map for that subsurface water). This is an important concept because it's soil pores packed with water that could lead to water pushing up from below onto your slab.
You already have the exterior french drain, and I thought those were meant to be superior systems (and more expensive). So, wondering what I must be missing in this comparison, I came across this 3rd image. How is the slab drained in this image? It appears to be a sump pit that has porous connectivity with the gravel (lower porosity soil area) under the slab.

Do you have a sump pit and pump? Would installing one like in this 3rd image help drain water under the slab? These are the things I'd be considering and asking your installer about.
